# Stack images vertically to the right next to a video

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to make a column of images on the right of a centered video, but every time I manage to stack them, the video moves down. My goal is to keep the video centered in the top of the image and have a column of 4 images aligned in the right. Heres how the HTML5 code is going and de CSS so far.

```
    <body style="background-color:#f7f5f7;">
     <h1 align="center" class="Title">
      Virgen Del Apocalipsis
     </h1>

    <div class="parent">
     <img src="front_fotos\F1.JPG" height="166px" width="260px" style="float:right">
     <img src="front_fotos\F2.JPG" height="166px" width="260px" style="float:right">
     <img src="front_fotos\F3.JPG" height="166px" width="260px" style="float:right">
     <img src="front_fotos\F4.JPG" height="166px" width="260px" style="float:right">
    </div>

    <video style="float:center" class="center" muted autoplay loop controls >
      <source src="virgengrande.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="virgengrande.ogg" type="video/ogg">
      Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>

  </body>
```

CSS code:

```
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.Title {
  align: center;
  font-family: fantasy;
  padding: 25px;
}

.center {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 0%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .wrapper{
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

}
```

Below you can find the current state of the product, the 4 images on the top are the ones that need to be in a column at the right.

[Current state image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2cZv.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    .parent {
      display:grid;
      grid-row: 1;
      grid-column:1;
      position: absolute;
      right:0;
    }
```

You might need to add some responsive to this but should work.

Comment: HEY! Thank you so much, your solution actually made the basic idea of what i needed, all i need to do now is add some padding to the images so it doesnt stick to te whole right of the page, any ideas on that?

Comment: Also, the only problem im getting is that now the video that was centered, is on the left end of the page, im trying to fix it with % variations in css file, but would also aprecciate if you can help me out with that

Comment: Update: I got it :D, i deleted one of my CSS calls by accident, anything i need i will come to this comment sections :3 Thank you so much again!

Answer (score 0):

Try with add css to parent like

```
.parent {
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: right;
 }
```

and remove the float right css in images

Comment: I used your solution but it keeps showing the images stacked horizontally, wich is really strange becuse you are using the vertical align css tag. This happens even if i take the float roght style tag

Comment: are you got the answer

Comment: Not the 100% of the answer, im still having some issues with align and padding

Comment: okay i saw your comment that you got the answer

Comment: Yes indeed, thanks you so much again! I will get back in here if anything else pops up :D

Comment: I really recommend not using float. There's much better alternatives in this decade.